# Unexpected data writing result in MarkLogic

Tags: rdf, marklogic

I would like to write the following RDF data into MarkLogic:

```
<http://John> <http://have> 2112351960 .
<http://John> <http://have> 2.112351960E9 .
```

##### Expected result

The data in the database is as following:

```
<http://John> <http://have> 2112351960 .
<http://John> <http://have> 2.112351960E9 .
```

##### Actual result

There is only one RDF triple in the database.

```
<http://John> <http://have> 2112351960 .
```

#### Alternatives

I can get expected result in Apache Jena and RDF4j.

Can someone give me an answer or a hint about it?

Comment: Those numbers are equal though. You are looking to have them be distinctly different as different types of numbers i.e. xs:integer vs xs:double?

Answer (score 3):

This is the result of the entailment regime supported:

https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-entailment/

MarkLogic implements D-entailment (datatype aware).

https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-entailment/#DEntRegime

I believe Jena implements simple entailment, which is unaware of datatype considerations.